# Python 3.6 | Error Importing package "tweepy"

Tags: package, anaconda, python-import, spyder, tweepy

### Runtime Error while importing package tweepy in python 3.6

I am trying to Install and Import Package Tweepy on Pyhton 3.6 running on Windows 10. 
Using Anaconda Prompt I am successfully able to pip install the package "tweepy", But when I open Spyder to import the same package, I am facing following runtime error:

```
File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 271, in find_module

    "not {}".format(type(path))) RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
```

Any help on what could be the reason for this error is much appreciated, Thanks in advance !

## Details

**Result after installing "tweepy" using Anaconda Prompt :**

```
(C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3) C:\Users\mohit>pip install -U tweepy
Requirement already up-to-date: tweepy in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.7.3 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.4.3 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.3->tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.3->tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.3->tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.3->tweepy)
Requirement already up-to-date: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in c:\users\mohit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)
```

---

### Error after running command import tweepy on spyder Console:

'

> import tweepy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-9d8dd8a91c0e>", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler, AppAuthHandler

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\auth.py", line 9, in <module>
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session, OAuth1

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .oauth2_auth import OAuth2

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_auth.py", line 2, in <module>
    from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient, InsecureTransportError

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .rfc6749.clients import Client

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .base import Client, AUTH_HEADER, URI_QUERY, BODY

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.parameters import (parse_token_response,

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 17, in <module>
    from oauthlib.signals import scope_changed

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\signals.py", line 9, in <module>
    from blinker import Namespace

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 864, in _find_spec_legacy

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 253, in find_module
    fp, pathname, (ext,mode,ty) = imp.find_module(fullname,package_path)

  File "C:\Users\mohit\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 271, in find_module
    "not {}".format(type(path)))

RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
'
```

---

OS : Windows 10, 64 bit
Anaconda 3
Python Version : 3.6

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a known [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5299) in Spyder. Please read the thread related to it for a temporary workaround until we fix it.